# Adding new JNI file to custom Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-framework

I have created a JNI file in AOSP at
framework\base\core\java\com\mydomain\mypackage\MyClass.java

which internally call the c files of framework\base\core\jni\mydomain\my_clas.cpp

But after compilation MyClass is not avilable through the custom SDK.

Please anybody help me to include custom JNI code in to Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add my_clas.cpp file to `frameworks/base/core/jni/Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
       mydomain_mypackage_my_clas.cpp
```

This adds your .cpp file to platform.

For adding your `MyClass.java` file to `Android SDK` update `Android API` file (where are described all classes, which are included in `SDK`. Location of that file `frameworks/base/api/current.txt`):

```
make update-api
```

Then compile your SDK for Linux platform (for example):

```
make PRODUCT-sdk-sdk
```

Your Android SDK with custom class (`MyClass.java`) will be located at `out/host/linux-x86/` in zip archive.

Use compiled custom `Android SDK` in your favorite `IDE` and easily call `MyClass.java`